# sql server sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I am using SQL Server's `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure to send mail via the database.

But when I execute that procedure it's shutting down the db mail procedure. I tried to start it again by `sysmail_start_sp`. But it's again shutting down in 7-8 seconds.

I tried with the code below:

```
EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Test',
@recipients = 'abc@gmail.com',
@subject = 'test mail',
@body_format = 'HTML',
@body = 'test mail',
@from_address = 'xyz@yahoo.com'
```

When I tried to check the error log I found the below error:

> Message:
>
> The read on the database failed. Reason: The error description is
>   'Whitespace is not allowed at this location.'.Data:
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternalTargetSite:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Objects.QueueItem
>   GetQueueItemFromCommand(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)HelpLink:
>   NULLSource: DatabaseMailEngineStackTrace
>   Information===================

Also when I checked sql email log history I found this error:

> Mail not queued. Database Mail is stopped. Use sysmail_start_sp to start Database 
>   Mail.

Comment: What is the version of your SQL Server? `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Check `@recipients,@copy_recipients,@blind_copy_recipients` for spaces. Check also `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_unsentitems` `SELECT * FROM sysmail_faileditems` for failed/retrying and search spaces

Answer (score 12):

Whenever you try to send Test mail from Database mail;  it throws below error message:

> Msg 14641, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail,  Mail not
>   queued. Database Mail is stopped. Use sysmail_start_sp to start
>   Database Mail.

---

1. First of all  make sure that Service Broker Message Delivery in Databases is enabled by executing the following command in SSMS:

   ```
   SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'msdb'
   ```

   If the result of above query is 0, then activate the service broker.

   Activating Service Broker allows messages to be delivered to the database. A Service Broker endpoint must be created to send and receive messages from outside of the instance.

   To activate Service Broker in a database use the following command:

   ```
   USE master ;
   GO

   ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET ENABLE_BROKER ;
   GO
   ```
2. If the Service Broker is enabled then confirm whether Database Mail is enabled or not by executing below queries in SQL Server Management Studio:

   ```
   sp_configure 'show advanced', 1
   GO

   RECONFIGURE
   GO

   sp_configure
   GO
   ```

   If the result set shows run_value as 1 then Database Mail is enabled.
3. If the Database Mail option is disabled then run the below queries to enable it:

   ```
   sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1; 
   GO

   RECONFIGURE;
   GO

   sp_configure 'show advanced', 0; 
   GO

   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
   ```
4. Once the Database Mail is enabled then to start Database Mail External Program use the below mentioned query on msdb database:

   ```
   USE msdb ;       
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp;
   ```
5. To confirm that Database Mail External Program is started, run the query mentioned below :

   ```
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp;
   ```
6. If the Database Mail external program is started then check the status of mail queue using below statement:

   ```
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'mail';
   ```

Comment: Excellent answer. Can even shorten to `USE msdb ;       
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp;` and then if it has still stopped then can follow whole question.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to troubleshoot, firstly check to make sure database Mail is enabled by executing the following

```
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'msdb'
```

If the result of above is `0`, activate the service broker by following [this guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166086(v=sql.105).aspx)

If the result of above is `1`, then check the status of Database Mail, execute the following statement:

```
EXECUTE dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp
```

To start Database Mail in a mail host database, run the following command in the msdb database:

```
EXECUTE dbo.sysmail_start_sp
```

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
USE msdb ;  
GO  
  
EXECUTE dbo.sysmail_start_sp ;  
GO
```

visit there

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sysmail-start-sp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16